# Spring JPA Repositories: How to send default value to parameter if criteria is not matching

Tags: spring, jpa, orm, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public interface WANRepository  extends JpaRepository<WANConfiguration,Long>{
    @Query("select ads from WANConfiguration as ads where ?1 BETWEEN ads.minAge AND ads.maxAge AND ads.expiryTime >?2 and ads.region=?3 and ads.gender=?4")
    List<WANConfiguration> findByAllAdsForUser(Integer userAge,Date currentTime,String region, String gender);
}
```

and here is the calling code

```
List<WANConfiguration> list = fanRepository.findByAllAdsForUser(userAgeInYear, new Date(),userLocation.getRegionName(), user.getGender().name());
```

Now there is a case where i want to pass default region i.e., userLocation.getRegionName(), so how can i do that and what are the changes required to do in db and repository or Query?

Comment: Can you clear what you asking here? You want to pass default region when `userLocation.getRegionName()` is empty/null and so on?

Comment: Yes Exactly... I want to pass a default region when it is null or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create method layer above:

```
List<WANConfiguration> findByAllAdsForUser(Integer userAge,Date currentTime,String region, String gender) {
     if(region == null || region.isEmpty()) {
         String defaultRegion = "what you want";
         return findByAllAdsForUser(userAge, currentTime, defaultRegion, gender);
     } 
     return findByAllAdsForUser(userAge, currentTime, region, gender);
}
```

Comment: did the same and got result. Actually i am new to JPA and Spring and i thought something different that's why i was bit confused...
Thanx...

@ByeBye

Comment: It is good approach to do it this way. If I helped please accept my answer.